# htaccess redirection for language query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I developed a php website, I'm using language script which displays English version if lang query string is en, German for de and so on. So the url was website.com/?lang=en, to make it seo friendly I used `RewriteRule ^((en|de|cz|hu|ro|sk)?)/(.*) /$3?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`
now the problem is it displays correct language for website.com/en but it also displays same on website.com/en/en/en/.
I want to redirect to 404 or to one time /en/.

And I want to set auto redirect from website.com/?lang=en to website.com/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s(.+)?\?lang=(en|de|cz|hu|ro|sk)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^         /%2%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|cz|hu|ro|sk)/((?!((en|de|cz|hu|ro|sk)/)).*) /$2?lang=$1 [L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.